# Download all files from web using Python error

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I am trying to download all files from this website https://superbancos.gob.pa/es/fin-y-est/reportes-estadisticos

I found this code on a page and I am trying to adapt it to my process

If you could help me I would appreciate it

```
#Aqui importe las librerias
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
  

  
# specify the URL of the archive here 
archive_url = "https://www.superbancos.gob.pa/es/fin-y-est/reportes-estadisticos"
  
def get_video_links(): 
      
   
    r = requests.get(archive_url) 
      
  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html5lib') 
      
    
    links = soup.findAll('a') 
  
    video_links = [archive_url + link['href'] for link in links if link['href'].endswith('xlsx')] 
  
    return video_links 
  
  
def download_video_series(video_links): 
  
    for link in video_links: 
  
        '''iterate through all links in video_links 
        and download them one by one'''
          
        # obtain filename by splitting url and getting  
        # last string 
        file_name = link.split('/')[-1]    
  
        print ("Downloading file:{!s}".format(file_name))
          
        # create response object 
        r = requests.get(link, stream = True) 
          
        # download started 
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f: 
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024*1024): 
                if chunk: 
                    f.write(chunk) 
          
        print ("{!s} downloaded!\n".format(file_name))
  
    print ("All files downloaded!")
    return
  
  
if __name__ == "__main__": 
  
  
    video_links = get_video_links() 
  
 
    download_video_series(video_links)
```

but when i start the program he said All files downloaded and dont download anyone

Comment: `print(r.content)` tells me you didn't get the right content.

Comment: you should check this part ```archive_url + link['href']``` because the link from `href` itself already a complete url

Answer (score 2):

The information you are looking for is dynamically loaded with JS code. So you should use something that can run JS and render the page like you see it in the browser.

The most straightforward way is using selenium:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

def get_soup(link):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')
    driver.close()
    return soup
```

So your first function could be rewritten as

```
def get_video_links(): 
    soup = get_soup(archive_url)
    links = soup.findAll('a') 
    video_links = [archive_url + link['href'] for link in links if link['href'].endswith('xlsx')] 
    return video_links
```

Just make sure to set up your ChromeDriver properly! here is the [documentation](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started).

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, I have this code now, it seems that it will work but I get an error

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here is that the page is required javascript. Your best bet here is to use selenium webdriver to handle this, instead of bs4:
[image]

Comment: I understand bro, i am newbie on coding, i install selenium and import to my python, 
Can I adapt this code to use it with selenium or do I have to make one from scratch? And thank so much for your help

Comment: you probably can adapt the code at least the logic how to get the links. You'll need to learn the basics of selenium to get this working like you want it to. My advise is that you start to set it up first and load the page, then get all the elements that you need. here is a starting point: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html